# How to show an iBeacon in a map

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

Once an app finds a beacon is possible to show both in a map (the device that found the beacon and the beacon itself)? If so how can i do that? I tried work with the distance bit with no success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't just find the exact location of an iBeacon once it's detected. You can only estimate its distance away from the device.

The `proximity` property tells you the relative distance (far, immediate, or close) that the beacon is away from the device while the `accuracy` property tells you how accurate that value is; so you can use proximity in combination with accuracy to get a general approximation of the distance. You could also potentially use these properties in combination with the RSSI, i.e. the received signal strength of the beacon, to further approximate the relative distance.

The device on the other hand can be mapped easily by turning on the map's `showsUserLocation` property.

Comment: I can get a proximity value of the beacon using accuracy property, right? With that i can draw a circle centered on user location to tell the user the possible location of the beacon (within the circumference), there is no way to get the direction the beacon is? With that i could estimate where in the circle may be the beacon.

Comment: @douglasd3 No, you can use the *proximity* property in combination with the *accuracy*. Proximity tells you the approximate distance the beacon is away from the device (far, near, or, immediate), while the accuracy tells you how accurate that value is. You could also potentially use these properties in combination with the RSSI to approximate the relative distance of the beacon from the device. And yes, you can use a circumference in the way you specify, but the direction can't be detected automatically... Perhaps you can use device movement and changing proximity to narrow down the direction.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your map is a MKMapView. If you know the precise location of the beacon (by having use a GPS to get the coordinates of the beacon when you have installed it) you can add an annotation on your MKMapView.

Take a look at MKMapView - (void)addAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation method for that.

If you don't have a database where to fetch the GPS coordinates of your beacons, there is no way to display them on a map as a beacon knows nothing about its surroundings.

By the way the accuracy property of a CLBeacon object isn't reliable enough for positioning.